# New post question notification on top notification bar

Tags: feature-request, notifications

May be this question is for stackexchange but i stick on askubuntu  i always visit askubuntu not stackexchange. so my question is, is it possible to notify by the top notification bar when new question is posted, if i open askubuntu.com/questions and/or readying some question.  this is not a lazy question :) it is just prevent refresh every time to see the new questions. also it is will be nice for someone who has a slow internet connection like me.

it is just make the site more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better idea might be to use a browser extension or applet built with the Stack Exchange API. For example, here's [one for Chrome](https://stackapps.com/questions/587/new-q-google-chrome-extension-notifies-you-of-new-questions-of-interest), and [another one](https://stackapps.com/questions/1699/askubuntu-add-on-for-firefox-opera-and-chrome) for Firefox, Chrome and Opera, that does exactly what you want, and more. Find more of these apps on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).

You can also try following the [Ask Ubuntu twitter feed](http://twitter.com/askubuntufeed) or the [RSS feed](https://askubuntu.com/feeds). In short, there are so many ways to be informed of new questions, there really isn't a need to build something like this into the site itself.